# Why both the typeclass and implicit argument mechanism?

Tags: lean

So we can have explicit arguments, denoted by `()`.
We can also have implicit arguments, denoted by `{}`.

So far so good.

However, why do we also need the `[]` notation for type classes specifically?

What is the difference between the following two:

```
theorem foo  {x : Type} : ∀s : inhabited x, x := sorry
theorem foo' {x : Type} [s : inhabited x] : x := sorry
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit arguments are inserted automatically by Lean's elaborator. The `{x : Type}` that appears in both of your definitions is one example of an implicit argument: if you have `s : inhabited nat`, then you can write `foo s`, which will elaborate to a term of type `nat`, because the `x` argument can be inferred from `s`.

Type class arguments are another kind of implicit argument. Rather than being inferred from later arguments, the elaborator runs a procedure called *type class resolution* that will attempt to generate a term of the designated type. (See chapter 10 of https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/theorem_proving_in_lean.pdf.) So, your `foo'` will actually take no arguments at all. If the expected type `x` can be inferred from context, Lean will look for an instance of `inhabited x` and insert it:

```
def foo' {x : Type} [s : inhabited x] : x := default x
instance inh_nat : inhabited nat := ⟨3⟩
#eval (2 : ℕ) + foo' -- 5
```

Here, Lean infers that `x` must be `nat`, and finds and inserts the instance of `inhabited nat`, so that `foo'` alone elaborates to a term of type `nat`.